# Counting by factors of two with a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I want this while loop to print every multiple of two below the number submitted(ex. if 100 was submitted it would print 2 4 8 16 32 64).  Here's what I have(I'm only going to include a portion of the class because there was other things in it that don't pertain to this part)

```
    i = 1;
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Would thoughst be inclined to enter a number fair sir/madam: ");
    String answer = myScanner.nextLine();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(answer);
    System.out.print("Your number set is: ");
    while(i <= number)
    {
    i = 2*i;
    System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
    }
```

What this prints if I enter 100 is: 2 4 8 16 32 64 128

How do I get rid of that last number?

Comment: If you want to print every multiple of two. Start from 0 and increment by 2 at each iteration...

Comment: Your title says "factors", your description says "multiples", and your code says "powers". Please make up your mind. (Well, technically your title says "counting by factors", which would mean counting by 1's and/or 2's.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
while( i <= number / 2)
```

Comment: If he swaps the two statements in the loop body, he also has to adjust the starting value of `i`.

Comment: ajb is, of course right. Never mind the suggestion in my comment.

Comment: No, I think the suggestion in your comment may be the best approach, as long as `i` is initialized properly.

Comment: Yes, as long as `number` is less than 2 to the 30.

Answer (score 2):

You would get rid of that number by modifying your logic to match. Your code is doing precisely what it says. One option is to start at 2, and increase `i` at the *end* of the loop instead of just before printing it. You could also use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 100; i *= 2)
    ...
```

If you want to save the last power, you have a few options, e.g.:

```
int k = 2;
for (int i = k; i < 100; i *= 2) {
    k = i;
    ...
}
```

Or undo the last operation:

```
int i;
for (i = 2; i < 100; i *= 2)
    ...;
i /= 2;
```

Or check the next one:

```
int i;
for (i = 2; i * 2 < 100; i *= 2)
    ...;
```

Checking the next one, in your original form:

```
while (i * 2 <= number)
    ...;
```

Etc.

By the way, your title says "factors", your description says "multiples", and your code says "powers"...

Comment: That won't help. He wants to end at a given value.

Comment: @Stendika He never said that; but I have added examples anyways.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
while(i <= number)
{
i = 2*i;
System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
}
```

the problem is that `i`, when it is equal to `64`, is indeed less than `100`, so the loop continues.

If you change it to

```
 i = 2*i;
 while(i <= number)  
 {
    System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
    i = 2*i;
 }
```

it does as you wish, because it *pre-computes* the value before being analyzed as the while-loop terminator.

Answer (score 1):

1. Those are powers of 2, not factors of 2.
2. "thoughst" is not a word. It should be "thou".
3. Update the value of i *after* you print it.